# What is the purpose of heap in stack based java virtual machine?

Tags: java, jvm

I heard that JVM is a stack based virtual machine then please let me know the purpose of heap structure for garbage collection in stack based virtual machine.

In stack based virtual machine, operations are carried out by popping data from stack, processing them and puhing in back the results in LIFO format.

From the above statement, if operands are stored in stack format, then please let me know where is the scope of heap structure. Does this stack based virtual machine also uses heap structure?

Comment: It seems you confuse Java heap with the heap data structure. These are different concepts.

Comment: Stack and heap are two different kinds of memory in a machine, including in the JVM. Heap is where objects and other things live. Stack is where method "frames" (including arguments) and local variables live. (This is a simplification.) Reference variables contain either `null` or pointers to objects on the heap.